# Using PyQGIS to make a custom measure tool that persists

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, pyqgis-3

Similar to how Google Earth works where you can draw out a measure line, then click the draw line or draw poly button to draw a feature and the measure line stays on the map. How could I modify the existing measure tool in my qgis plugin so that the measure lines persist when editing a layer?

Answer (score 2):

This capability is built into QGIS.  No modifications are needed.

1. Ensure that your QGIS project is using a Cartesian coordinate system like UTM.
2. Create a new line layer like a shapefile or a geopackage that also references the same coordinate reference system as your map.
3. Start an edit session on your newly created line layer.
4. Open the measure line tool on the attribute toolbar and make sure the dialog box is open and visible (see the image below).
5. Create a new line.  The length of that line will be visible in the measure line tool while you are drawing. You will be able to see segment lengths and the total length (see the image below).
6. Save your new line feature.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @CBG oh wow, I did not know this, thank you. I'm actually triggering draw mode through pyqgis, I wonder if I could make this measure window pop up at the same time in my pyqgis code?

Comment: I don't know about that but GIS Stack Exchange comments are not meant to have running dialogs.  Post a new question on opening the measure tool dialog box with pyqgis.  If you found my answer useful please accept the answer, thanks.